# Windows 8.1 RDP to Windows 7 Pro cannot login with domain account

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

At work I have a Windows 7 Pro that my account on it logs into our domain server.  At home, my Windows 7 Home Premium can RDP into that machine just fine using my regular username "Steve" (i.e. not OURDOMAIN.Steve.  However, my new home machine is 8.1 (not pro either), when I connect as "Steve" a new temporary profile is created and none of "my" stuff is accessible.  How can I get my 8.1 to RDP into my office computer to get my correct account?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do.  In general, you need to specify the domain. `ourDomain\Steve` as the user name. If the Steve account you want to use is a local account on the Window 7 work machine then you'd use `theMachinesName\Steve` If you ARE successfully logging into the computer using the account you want, and you're having a temporary profile created, then that sounds like your user profile is corrupted o the work machine, have you confirmed it's not? Can you log into that machine locally as the user you're attempting to log in with from home?

Comment: Thank you!  I was using dot notation (OURDOMAIN.Steve).  D'oh!

Comment: Cool, I'll stick it in as an answer. :)  PS steve@domain would probably work as well. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the domain. IE: `ourDomain\Steve` as the user name. If the Steve account you want to use is a local account on the Windows 7 work machine (not a domain account) then you'd use `theMachinesName\Steve`.

If you want a bit more info, here's a related StackOverflow question that discusses a couple alternative ways to do it:

[Any difference between DOMAIN\username and username@domain.local?](https://serverfault.com/questions/371150/any-difference-between-domain-username-and-usernamedomain-local)

If you ARE successfully logging into the computer using the account you want, and you're having a temporary profile created, then that sounds like your user profile is corrupted on the work machine